# Draw true page border

Tags: margins, framed, geometry

Is there a way to draw a rectangle around every page?

The problem is that my document (a Ph.D. thesis) is in a *funny* format (16x24cm). So to print it centered on A4 paper (for reviewing) I played with the page layout.

However, I would like to have indication of the **true page size** with means of a rectangle drawn around each page. Is it possible? BTW. I use `pdflatex`.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the [`crop`](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/help/Catalogue/entries/crop.html) package to place your pages on a A4 paper. It can center and frame it for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=24cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,frame,center]{crop}

\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\begin{document}
\lipsum
\lipsum
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

It looks like this:

[image: Result]

If you don't like the info line above the frame use the `noinfo` package option.

Comment: Ui, the package works great, but synctex gets confused... Any idea how to make both crop and synctex-pdf-linking to work together?

Comment: @ronszon: Sorry, I can't help you here. I never used `synctex` so far. You might ask this as a follow-up question.

Comment: @MartinScharrer is there a way to change color and thickness of this borer?

Comment: I can use the command without the `center` as it appears above, which I would like: `\usepackage[a4,frame]{crop}` This way I can  make the border to appear as a single line at the bottom. **Is it possible to place just a single line below for cutting** (instead of a complete square border) **?**

Comment: @nilon: Well, please check the manual of `crop` if it support such a thing. All I could do is doing the exact same thing.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using geometry for setting the page parameters, then add the option `showframe` or `showcrop`

Comment: geometry doesn't seem to have a `showcrop` option.

Comment: @FaheemMitha Version 5.6 has it.

Comment: egreg: Ok. I am using 4.2 (Tex Live 2009).

Comment: This way is excellent to remove (large amounts of) badboxes from the draft of a (large sized) document.

Answer (score 11):

I had a similar issue with my own thesis. The way I dealt with it issue was to use features of the PDF format. PDF allows a file to specify several different boxes: TrimBox, MediaBox, ArtBox, CropBox, BleedBox. Relevant to this situation is MediaBox: the size of the paper you are printing on (in your case A4); and TrimBox: the size of the page after trimming. Many PDF viewers (Adobe Reader for example) are able to display these boxes optionally. I don't know of any packages that make use of this feature (would make a nice modification to `geometry` or `crop`), so I did it by hand: `\pdfpageattr{/TrimBox[9 9 621 801]}` where if I recall correctly the units are in pts. You can see a result [here](http://levbishop.org/thesis/source/Bishop-thesis-lulucolour.pdf), where I wanted the final page to be US Letter size, but to have a 0.125" bleed before trimming. If you are using Adobe Reader, then to show the boxes use Edit -> Preferences -> Page Display -> Show art, trim, & bleed boxes.

Answer (score 4):

The [`crop`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/crop.html) packages does it for the general case. See also [What is the easiest way to get borders around a page in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/801/3083) and in particular the [solution for the Memoir document class.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/801/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-borders-around-a-page-in-latex/810#810)

Answer (score 2):

try using this :

```
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{3pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}
\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
\setlength{\parindent}{2cm}
```

Comment: Can you extend the question by some explanations and maybe a screenshot?

Comment: Ideally, write up a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) to show its use, rather than just code snippets.

Comment: This solution causes page numbers in the table of contents to be off by 1