# Inverse search jumps to wrong position in tex-file if using crop package

Tags: pdftex, crop, forward-inverse-search

When using `pdflatex` I generate a `synctex` file for inverse search. So far, pointing and clicking in the PDF viewer (SumatraPDF) brings me to the correct line in the TeX editor (TeXnicCenter).

However, if I use the [`crop`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/crop) package, almost all line numbers that the inverse search gives are wrong (by offsets of some lines). Clicking in the PDF brings me too far in `tex` source. This is quite annoying and definitely not how it should be.

Example (**updated**):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a3,frame,center]{crop} %without this package inverse search works fine!
% (We let "crop" print on a3 paper to be able to see the produced frame.)
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{The first lipsum}
\lipsum
% the cursor should be placed around this line by the inverse search of
% the  ***last lines***  of above lipsum text in the PDF
\section{The second lipsum}
\lipsum
% but the cursor appears at the next line!
\section{The third lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Any ideas how to solve it? BTW, where is `synctex` maintained?

FYI, for this example, `\listfiles` outputs (**updated**)

```
*File List*
article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
    crop.sty    2003/05/20 v1.9 crop marks (mf)
  color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
  color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
ltxcmds.sty    2011/11/09 v1.22 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
  lipsum.sty    2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/11/29 v0.20 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
  ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Manage graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Define keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2011/06/30 v3.11 Key value format for package options (HO)
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
kvsetkeys.sty    2012/04/25 v1.16 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
```

<sub>Just to note, the following files are not used by the *updated* example:
`geometry.sty`, `ifvtex.sty`, `ifxetex.sty`, `crop.cfg`, `atbegshi.sty`.</sub>

<sub>And the versions of some files changed. The old versions were:
`ifpdf.sty(v2.1)`, `pdftex.def(v0.05d)`, `lipsum(v1.1)`, `ltxcmds(v1.7)`,
`pdftexcmds.sty(v0.9)`, `grfext.sty(v1.0)`, `kvoptions.sty(v3.7)`,
`kvsetkeys.sty(v1.9)`, `etexcmds.sty(v1.3)`.</sub>

Comment: On Mac OS X, with Aquamacs and Skim, it works perfectly.

Comment: This seems to be a follow-up question to [Draw true page border](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/15052/2975) where the `crop` package was mentioned as solution.

Comment: So far the problem still exists... To make it more evident, I updated the MWE. The `geometry` package was removed since the problem occurs without it, too.

Answer (score 1):

(More of a comment)

This seems to be 'works for me' with the `\listfiles` output

```
*File List*
 article.cls    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  keyval.sty    1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
  ifvtex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.5 Switches for detecting VTeX and its modes (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
    crop.sty    2003/05/20 v1.9 crop marks (mf)
   color.sty    2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
  pdftex.def    2011/05/27 v0.06d Graphics/color for pdfTeX
infwarerr.sty    2010/04/08 v1.3 Providing info/warning/message (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2011/04/18 v1.20 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
graphics.sty    2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
    crop.cfg
  lipsum.sty    2011/04/14 v1.2 150 paragraphs of Lorem Ipsum dummy text
atbegshi.sty    2011/01/30 v1.15 At begin shipout hook (HO)
supp-pdf.mkii
pdftexcmds.sty    2011/04/22 v0.16 Utilities of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
epstopdf-base.sty    2010/02/09 v2.5 Base part for package epstopdf
  grfext.sty    2010/08/19 v1.1 Managing graphics extensions (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.3 Defining keys (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2010/12/23 v3.10 Keyval support for LaTeX options (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2011/04/07 v1.13 Key value parser (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2011/02/16 v1.5 Prefix for e-TeX command names (HO)
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2010/07/13 v1.3 Configuration of (r)epstopdf for TeX Live
 ***********
```

and tested using TeX Live 2010 and 2011. Can you provide more version information, otherwise this looks 'too localized' to me.

Comment: With pleasure. Both tools are brilliant so would be great to get it working together :D

Comment: @ronszon Could you post which TeX biarny you are using (the line that says `TeX 3.141...`)?

Comment: Do you mean if I use pdflatex? (I removed copyright info, sorry)

    pdfTeX 3.1415926-1.40.11-2.2 (Web2C 2010)
    kpathsea version 6.0.0
    Compiled with libpng 1.4.3; using libpng 1.4.3
    Compiled with zlib 1.2.5; using zlib 1.2.5
    Compiled with xpdf version 3.02pl4

Comment: @JosephWright Does the MWE still work for you without problems? My changes of MWE consist mainly of the removal the comment in front of `\usepackage{crop}` and the addition of `\section`'s to make the problem more evident. It'd be great if you could check the modified MWE, too.

Comment: It does not work for me. Backwards search is still off by at least a few lines.

Answer (score 0):

A first try. Add the following lines *after* loading the `crop` package. (Note, this creates overfull boxes!)

```
%\usepackage[........]{crop}  must comes before the patch!
%------ our patch
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\CROP@kernel{\hb@xt@\z@}{}{}{}
\makeatother
%------
```

To the details.

1. The `crop` package draws the frame etc. by using `picture`-environments. Inverse search does not work well with the original definition of `picture`-environment, but the [`pict2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pict2e) package redefines it in a way inverse search can work with.
2. For drawing the frame etc. the `picture` environments are nested in boxes of type `\vbox` and `\hbox`. A small modification of the `crop` package by using the `\patchcmd` of the `etoolbox` package will make the inverse search work properly but **at the cost of overfull boxes!!**

Here the complete MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[a3,frame,center]{crop}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd\CROP@kernel{\hb@xt@\z@}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\section{The first lipsum}
\lipsum

\section{The second lipsum}
\lipsum

\section{The third lipsum}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```