# SyncTeX backward sync off when using crop with the frame option

Tags: forward-inverse-search

When using the [`crop`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/crop) package with the `frame` option, SyncTeX' inverse search always seems to be a bit off.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a5paper]{report}

\usepackage[a4, center, frame]{crop}

\begin{document}
Foo

Bar

Baz
\end{document}
```

Without the `frame` option, inverse search works normally but with it, inverse search always jumps to the `\end{document}` line.

There seems to be a [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/16174/inverse-search-jumps-to-wrong-position-in-tex-file-if-using-crop-package) which, unfortunately, does not have an answer.

*Note: I removed most of the original question since it isn't relevant anymore now that I found a MWE.*

Comment: How to you organise your source files? Do you break lines at 80 character or do you break lines at paragraph?  If you have entire paragraph (let us say of 800 characters ~ 10 lines) without line break  in the source, the backward search cannot be precise since 10 lines in the pdf correspond to the same line of the source file (a line of 800 characters).

Comment: @Guido: I break lines after every sentence. But I don't think this really matters because SyncTeX seems to be storing column information.

Comment: I think you can try harder to make an MWE. See [some suggestions here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that). E.g. you can cut off halves of document and see if the issue persists, remove packages and see if the issue persists, and then finally you can change/randomize all the words in your document so that the text is meaningless, but the issue is present.

Comment: Is it editor specific?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/59822/90087

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: You're right, I should have spent some more time on it. Please see my edit for a MWE.

Comment: @cfr: No, it is not.