# Printing A6 on A4 paper

Tags: paper-size, printing

Yesterday I encountered a problem with printing an A6 pdf document (which I created using LaTeX).
The Printing shop did not have A6 sheets, so they took the print out on an A4, which turned out different than what I expected it to – it was magnified in the print.

I have few questions to ask, please help me out:

1. Is it possible to put A6 page with border, so I could get printout of any sized paper, and then cut it using the border?
2. Can I put multiple (x,y) on (a,b) paper? Here paper size is mention with this convention (width, height) and (a,b) bigger than (x,y). As show in the image below.
   Ex:
   6 orange-size sheets on one green-size sheet, with border for cutting the paper into A6 after the printing?
3. Is it possible to arrange smaller sheets in any order on a bigger sheet?
   Like consecutive sheets row wise or column wise? Below I have mentioned the page numbers and arrangement.

```
(1, 2, 3)      (1, 4, 7)
(4, 5, 6)  or  (2, 5, 8)
(7, 8, 9)      (3, 6, 9)
```

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`pdfpages` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages) provides exactly this functionality.

Assume that you have a document that has been created in LaTeX on A6-sized paper (the example below creates a 29-page document, `mya6doc.pdf` say):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\begin{document}
\chapter{First chapter} \lipsum[1-10]
\chapter{Second chapter} \lipsum[11-20]
\chapter{Third chapter} \lipsum[21-30]
\chapter{Final chapter} \lipsum[31-40]
\end{document}
```

Now create *another* document `mya4doc` using the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{pdfpages}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pdfpages
\begin{document}
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x2,frame,noautoscale]{mya6doc}%
\end{document}
```

`pdfpages` options allow for the inclusion of *all* pages (`pages=-`) in a *2x2 nup* format (`nup=2x2`) with a *border*<sup>1</sup> around each page (`frame`). Also, pages are left unscaled (`noautoscale`).

[image: pdfpages insert by-row pages (2x2 A6 onto A4)]

The default is to print pages using a row-first ordering. The can be modified to print using a column-first ordering<sup>3</sup> by adding the option `column`:

[image: pdfpages insert by-column pages (2x2 A6 onto A4)]

Note that in the above example, `nup=2x2` was used since A6 is 1/4 of A4. Therefore, the inserted pages remain exactly A6 and snugly fit side-by-side on A4. However, it is also possible to put 6 A6 pages on a A4 sheet, since `pdfpages` automatically scales the input pages to fit on the output pages (or any number<sup>2</sup> for that matter). The inserted pages will be reduced in size accordingly. For example, modifying the above to

```
\includepdf[pages=-,nup=2x3,frame,delta=2cm 0]{mya6doc}%
```

produces a 3x2 layout with a horizontal gap of 2cm between the inserted pages (and zero vertical gap):

[image: pdfpages insert by-row pages (3x2 reduced A6 onto A4)]

The [package documentation](http://mirror.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf) provides the rest of the options.

---

<sup>1</sup> Satisfies your first request.

<sup>2</sup> Satisfies your second request.

<sup>3</sup> Satisfies your third request.

Comment: `pdfpages` is also used by `pdfnup`, which creates that temporary tex file for you. On the other hand, using `pdfpages` you have more flexibility and can use all options of the `pdfpages` package... Drawback is that you have to create the second tex file manually.

Answer (score 4):

1. Paper border and printing one size on a larger-sized paper: You can use the crop package.

   - See also the answer [Draw true page border](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15052/draw-true-page-border/15055#15055)
   - Download: http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/crop
2. and 3. are probably best done with psnup or pdfnup.

   - pdfnup (part of pdfjam): http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/statistics/staff/academic-research/firth/software/pdfjam
   - psnup: http://www.tardis.ed.ac.uk/~ajcd/psutils/psnup.html

All those software packages are open source and usually installed on any Linux system. On Windows or Mac you can probably download a proper version, too.

If pdfnup does not fit your wishes, pdftk is another open source PDF package that can be very helpful: http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/

Comment: You don't have to sign with your name since it automatically appears in the lower right corner of your post.

Comment: @Reinhold, the two software you mentioned are proprietary software, free version allows for 10 sheets.

Comment: @Kirk, all software packages that I mentioned are open source and usually installed on any Linux system. On Windows or Mac you can probably also download a proper version.
I have updated the answer to include the download links.

Comment: BTW, `pdfnup` uses the `pdfpages` latex package recommended by Werner, so that you don't have to create that second text file manually. It's basically a "front-end" (cmd line) to `pdfpages`.