# Page number and logical pages

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, pdfpages

I used the following piece of code to put a box around each page in my report

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,final,times]{report}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
%\usepackage{fncychap}

\usepackage{lipsum,titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{simplemargins}
\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
\edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
{%
logical pages=1,%
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
{
border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
resized width=.90\pgfphysicalwidth,%
resized height=.85\pgfphysicalheight,%
center=\pgfpoint{.53\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
}%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
\pagestyle{fancy}
```

but this is causing my page numbers to be different from that of the toc. To be specific, page numbers in toc=page number on page +1.

Any solution for this, please? The code is borrowed from [this answer by Andrew Stacey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/808/4427)

Comment: You need to give more information: this code is useless without knowing the class used, for example, and all the packages used.

Comment: @egreg am sorry. I've edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. To make your question fit good question style here on tex.sx even better, it'd be nice if you could alter your example so that it _only_ contains what's necessary to reproduce your problem, but _everything_ that's necessary for other users to be able to copy and compile your code in order to see the problem. This is called a  [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/). Two things you'll have to do is removing some packages and adding a document body of a few pages. You'll be more likely to get an answer if you provide such code.

Comment: Well, that's what you get if you use dodgy code from some no-good halfwit who doesn't know his `\expandafter` from his `\romannumeral`.  *Caveat TeXtor* and all that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On page 515 of the PGF manual (which also documents `pgfpages`, I'm looking at the version for PGF2.10) it says:

> Another word of caution: *using **pgfpages** will produce wrong page numbers in the `.aux` file*.  The reason is that TeX instantiates the page numbers when writing an `.aux` file only when the physical page is shipped out.  Fortunately, this problem is easy to fix: First, typeset our file normally without using the `\pgfpagesuselayout` command (just put the comment marker `%` before it)[.] Then, rerun TeX with the `\pgfpagesuselayout` command included and add the command `\nofiles`.  This command ensures that the `.aux` file is not modified, which is exactly what you want.

I just tried it with the example in Peter's answer and it worked:

```
\documentclass{report}

\AtBeginDocument{\addtocontents{toc}{\protect\thispagestyle{empty}}} 

\usepackage{fancyheadings}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
\edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
\pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
{%
logical pages=1
}
\pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
{%
border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}\pgfstroke,%
border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
resized width=.90\pgfphysicalwidth,%
resized height=.85\pgfphysicalheight,%
center=\pgfpoint{.53\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
}%
}

% uncomment both of the next two lines on the final run through
%\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
%\nofiles
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\clearpage
\section{One}
\lipsum[1-12]
\section{Two}
\lipsum[12-25]
\end{document}
```