# Borders on all pages

Tags: xetex, border, pgfpages

I am working on a report and I want a border on all pages. I have managed to have a border by using the solution provided here:
https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/808/205277

But it won't work on all pages. Any ideas on how to do it? I so wanted to comment on the question itself for help but since I am new here I don't have enough reputation to do that so I had to post this as a separate question

LaTeX preamble:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\setsansfont[Scale=0.95,Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{babel}


\geometry{verbose,tmargin=1.6cm,bmargin=1.6cm,lmargin=10pt,rmargin=10pt}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum} %Just a package for generating garbage text which is not otherwise required 


\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{boxed}
{
  \edef\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
}
{
  \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
  {%
    logical pages=1,%
  }
  \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
  {
    border code=\pgfsetlinewidth{0.5pt}\pgfstroke,%
    border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
    resized width=.95\pgfphysicalwidth,%
    resized height=.95\pgfphysicalheight,%
    center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth}{.5\pgfphysicalheight}%
  }%
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{boxed}
```

Comment: Is this what you want? `\usepackage[margin=3cm]{geometry}`

Comment: @BlackMild I added my code so hope that helps you have a better understanding of what is going on. I am not setting a margin, I just want a border around my pages

Comment: you added some code but it is incomplete so no one can run it, and it does not give an example of a page where it does not work.

Comment: I sent just the LaTeX preamble and not the whole document because it's really big and wouldn't make much sense. I have seen most of these errors are caused by how packages are used, because sometimes these pages inherit properties from the ones above them. After the preamble for each page I just use `\pgfpagesuseslayout{boxed}`. It worked for the first page but not on others.

Comment: Hi, I think I have managed to make some progress over finding a solution. Earlier I thought that the reason the borders weren't present was the way the packages were written but now I now it is because of XeLaTeX. For some reason because of it 'pgfpages' is not working as usual. Can someone please suggest a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that this is an answer, certainly not pertaining to the specifics of your question, but to a generally wider question.

For some years I wrote a column for TUGboat, one of which considered putting borders around pages ( [https:/tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf](http://https:/tug.org/TUGboat/tb32-2/tb101glister.pdf) ). In particular page 3 of this shows a (fancy) bordered page and on page 4 the macro `\goddfoot` that was used to create the border.

Comment: That's some really good LaTeX... I'm just a beginner at all this. But I'll see if your approach towards borders helps me and let you know if it works