# Box around every page body

Tags: boxes, geometry, frame

I am defining page margins with `geometry`, adding a footer and header.
I want the body of the text (not the footer or header) to be enclosed in a box (every page).

This is a similar question to [What is the easiest way to get borders around a page in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/801/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-get-borders-around-a-page-in-latex) and other that I found, but them all are planned for a full border around the whole page (for cropping needs, for instance).

Suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but the `tikzpagenodes` provides tikz anchors for each block (text, footer, header...) and `background` provides `\AddEverypageHook` to add text on every page. Combining the two gives:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage[contents={}]{background}
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \tikz[remember picture,overlay]{
    \draw (current page text area.north east) -- (current page text area.north west)
          -- (current page text area.south west) -- (current page text area.south east) -- cycle;
  }
}

\begin{document}
Hello
\newpage
Hello
\end{document}
```

By adding options to the tikz drawing, you can easily customize it with dashed lines, colors…

Comment: Perfect. As you say, there might be a cleaner solution, but for me it works great. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

It can also be done with no packages.

```
\documentclass{article}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{\fboxsep=0pt
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \put({\dimexpr 1in+\oddsidemargin-\fboxrule},{\dimexpr -1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-\fboxrule})%
      {\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}}}
  \else
    \put({\dimexpr 1in+\evensidemargin-\fboxrule},{\dimexpr -1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-\fboxrule})%
      {\fbox{\rule{0pt}{\textheight}\rule{\textwidth}{0pt}}}
  \fi}

\begin{document}
Hello

\noindent\verb|\fboxsep| = \the\fboxsep
\newpage
Hello
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice suggestion....

Comment: How to exclude the first page?

Comment: @Stephen - `\ifnum\value{page}=1\else ... \fi`