# Grey border around the whole page

Tags: books, border

I am typesetting novels in Latex and I would like to include a 'if you like this, why not try' section at the back.

Such sections are normally formatted like this:

[image]

With a nice grey border around the page, that indicates this section is differnet. It's normally visible from the side as well:

[image]

How can I achive this effect in Latex? (personally I'd be fine with doing it post-hoc in a pdf editor, but I don't know how to do that either)

Comment: Joe have you tried https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/808/139814?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same result, but done at the package level, using tikz pagenodes, and setting the border command as the page header with `fancyhdr`, so you can add in other header material if you need to.

[image: page border]

Perhaps easier to maintain and modify, semantically speaking, depending on your coding style. Only two variables, colour and line width (with the "frame's" given x- and y-shift of 0).

I find no additional overhead loading `tikz`, so this solution may depend on your system constraints (if any).

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\gborder}{\tikz[remember picture,overlay] 
    \draw [black!10!blue!20,line width=18mm]
    (current page.south west)
    rectangle
    (current page.north east)
    ;}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead[C]{\gborder}
\renewcommand{\headrule}{}

\begin{document}

\section{A}
\lipsum[1-10]
\section{B}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very strangly this MWE gives me: https://twitter.com/JoeReddington/status/1480938959320633350/photo/1 - is that my setup or did something accidently hit the MWE?

Comment: Okay, I switched the 'north' and 'south' - and remembered to run it twice (possibly those two cancel each other out) and it's working perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: Compiling twice (or more) is needed because the contents need to "settle" (e.g. table of contents is populated on second run, shifting page numbers, so a third run is needed to get the refreshed page numbering into the TOC), and then the tikz picture clicks into position. "North" and "South" are shorthand-code for "top centre of the page rectangle" and "Bottom centre of the page rectangle", so swapping them around will still draw a rectangular-frame border around the page edges. North east = top right corner, and so on.

Answer (score 3):

LaTeX has hooks for every page (e.g. shipout/background). This one expect picture commands, eg `\put` the picture (0,0) is in the topleft corner, see `texdoc ltshipout-doc`. With this it is fairly simple to build fixed backgrounds, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor,kantlipsum}

\AddToHook{shipout/background}{%
  \linethickness{20pt}%
  \color{black!25}%
  \put(0,-10pt){\line(1,0){\paperwidth}}%
  \put(10pt,0){\line(0,-1){\paperheight}}%
  \put(0,-10pt){\line(1,0){\paperwidth}}%
  \put(\paperwidth-10pt,-\paperheight){\line(0,1){\paperheight}}%
  \put(\paperwidth,-\paperheight+10pt){\line(-1,0){\paperwidth}}%
  }

\begin{document}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Investigating - I'm running into a problem with \AddToHook - might be a problem with my setup...

Comment: @Joe Hook management was added in 2020-10 to LaTeX if I remember correctly. If your LaTex is still older than the solution will not work.