Creating an article with bordered pages like MS Word
Kindly guide me on how create page border for all pages using Lyx. I want to create articles with minimum 8 to 10 pages and each page should have page borders as like MS Word.

Can you show an example of a word document you'd like to replicate?

Image added sir

See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/808/4736 You can drop the code beginning with the line \usepackage{pgf} until \pgfpagesuselayout{boxed} into the preamble of a lyx document. There should be a configuration under the document menu.

In a normal document, you could do `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\AddToHook{shipout/foreground}{
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw ([shift={(1,1)}]current page.south west) rectangle ([shift={(-1,-1)}]current page.north east);
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}
test
\end{document}` No idea if this works in lyx

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Yes, in LyX you can paste code into a LaTeX-preamble window, menu document and then there is a config line. However, question is old and answered.
