# Is there a package to divide pages of A4 to 2 pages of A5 each?

Tags: packages, paper-size, crop

When I read a pdf book in my iPod touch using iBook software in landscape mode, I must zoom in each page manually. It means if I proceed to each page, I must zoom in until the left-right margins get aligned with the left-right margins of the display--- approximately 1/2 of a page will be displayed.

My idea is to divide each page in my book into 2 pages of A5. I hope I can do this for all pages automatically because doing it manually for more than 500 pages becomes tedious.

Is there a package to do that?

Comment: I am not sure I got this right, but maybe this question will be relevant: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-there-a-way-to-get-two-pages-in-one-with-latex

Comment: This problem is already solved. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got the solution. I will use [this pdf](http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf) to be splitted. After downloading, I rename it as MVC.pdf.

Acrobat Reader informs me that the pdf has a width of 7.38 inches and a height of 9.25 inches.

I hope the magic numbers in the code snippet below are self-explanatory. If not, read pdfpages manual. :-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.38in,paperheight=4.025in,margin=0mm]{geometry}

\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=50+1}{10}%
{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\i}}%
    {%
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.7in 4.325in 0.3in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
            \pagebreak          
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.7in 0.4in  0.3in 4.825in,clip]{MVC}%
    }%
    {%
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.3in 4.325in 0.7in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
            \pagebreak      
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.3in 0.4in  0.7in 4.825in,clip]{MVC}%
    }%
}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very much not a pretty solution, but, given that you know the number of pages, you could use a combination of the `forloop` package and `\includegraphics`. As a small example:

```
\newcounter{pg} 
\forloop{pg}{1}{\value{ct} < 5}% {%
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,clip,viewport=0mm 0mm 210mm 148mm,page=pg]{thingy.pdf}
\pagebreak
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth,clip,viewport=0mm 148mm 210mm 207mm,page=\value{pg}]{thingy.pdf}
}
```

A better solution than the for loop would be to use the `pdfpages` package somehow, but I could not see how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. By the way, can we detect the book size on the fly instead of hard-coding the viewport? It is because my book size might not be exactly A4.

Comment: I assume the default/full page bounding box dimensions have to be stored by includegraphics somewhere. I can't read the package well enough to tell. There is a set of keys in graphicx called natwidth and natheight and another set bburx, bbury, bbllx, bblly, but I don't know which is right or how to access them.