# How to pass the value of \mylength to the "trim" option of \includepdf of pdfpages.sty?

Tags: lengths, pdfpages, crop

This problem is related to my previous problem about [pdf trimming](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7123/is-there-a-package-to-divide-pages-of-a4-to-2-pages-of-a5-each/).

Here is the minimal code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6.38in,paperheight=4.025in,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\newlength{\mylength}
\setlength{\mylength}{0.7in}
\usepackage{multido}
\begin{document}
\multido{\i=50+1}{10}%
{%
    \ifthenelse{\isodd{\i}}%
    {%
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=\mylength 4.325in 0.3in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
            \pagebreak          
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.7in 0.4in  0.3in 4.825in,clip]{MVC}%
    }%
    {%
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.3in 4.325in 0.7in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
            \pagebreak      
            \includepdf[pages=\i,trim=0.3in 0.4in  0.7in 4.825in,clip]{MVC}%
    }%
}%
\end{document}
```

The pdf file to be trimmed is available [here](http://content.wrox.com/wroxfiles/aspnetmvc-nerdinner_v2.pdf). I rename the pdf as MVC.pdf and save it in the same directory in which the tex input file above is saved.

I compiled and got blank pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
\includepdf[pages=\i,trim=\mylength{} 4.325in 0.3in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
```

or

```
\includepdf[pages=\i,trim={\mylength} 4.325in 0.3in 0.9in,clip]{MVC}%
```

What is important is that the space after `\mylength` is not eaten by TeX.