# Can I convert a 16 page pdf into an 8x2 matrix in LaTeX?

Tags: pdfpages

My graphing program (R) can plot a set of figures out, each on a separate page of the same pdf. Is there a way to convert this into a single 4x4 or 8x2 figure in LaTeX? There are alternatives, but this would be preferable.

Comment: This question seems related to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7123/is-there-a-package-to-divide-pages-of-a4-to-2-pages-of-a5-each

Comment: If you choose `8x2` then each pdf becomes so small and you will need a magnifying glass to read the printed version. I recommend you to use `2x1` or `1x2` or `2x2`. More than this will be hard to read.

Comment: @xport in my case, each page is a simple xy plot, and I can adjust the dimensions and fonts as needed, I just need to be able to arrange them.

Comment: @xport: 4x4 sounds very small, but we can't say anything useful about readability if we don't see an example plot.

Comment: @Charles, I don't know the exact size of David's pdf files. So the decision depends on his feeling. :-)

Comment: I'd like to see a Context solution to this.  It should be possible using mplib.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is very easy. Please use `pdfpages.sty` and [click here for its manual](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/pdfpages/pdfpages.pdf).

---

### Sample Output

[image]

---

## Code Snippet Sample

I used a pdf file downloaded from [here](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/releases/view/53639#DownloadId=155995) and then renamed it as `movies.pdf`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\begin{document}
\includepdf[%
landscape=true,%
pages={1-16},%Include pages from 1 to 16.
nup=2x3,%If landscape=false then it defines columns x rows. Otherwise it defines rows by columns. 
]{movies.pdf}%Pdf file name with or without extension.
\end{document}
```