# Four smaller pages in one page

Tags: positioning, printing

I would like to style my document in such a way that the page is divided into four equal parts and then the text is printed in those pages: it is similar to `twocolumn` but I also want to have, say two rows. The reason is that I would like to cut the page into four smaller pieces, so it would be very convenient if LaTeX can do this.
Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: Very much related: [Is there a way to get two pages in one with latex?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/783/1235)

Comment: Thanks. But I do not want to do this to an external PDF file, but rather to my own file. Also, I prefer if the font sizes do not change. The documentation for pdfpages is very brief, so I am not sure if I can do this.

Comment: For SEO sake : how to split a page in four with LaTeX, quarter sheet flyers. ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could simply use [pdfnup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/pdfnup) (for PDF documents), or [psnup](http://linux.die.net/man/1/psnup) (for PostScript documents).

Comment: We can also generalize this advice to "use external tools". There are many dedicated utilities, most PDF/PS viewers allow setting this in printing options, and finally, many printer drivers/software themselves provide such functions.

Answer (score 5):

Building on Matthew Leingang's answer, here's some code that does 4 on 1.

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]
```

Put this somewhere in your preamble. (*After* hyperref, if you load hyperref).

This will put 4 pages on one. If you want to keep more or less the same text size, I'd suggest upping the text size in your documentclass call. With a little experimentation you should be able to find a size that looks acceptable.

Here's a quick MWE to show roughly how this may work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{anyfontsize} %For arbitrary font sizes
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}  
\usepackage{lipsum}  % For dummy text
\usepackage[margin=1cm]{geometry} % To make margins smaller
\usepackage{microtype}  % To improve hyphenation, justification etc...
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{4 on 1}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm]

\begin{document}
\fontsize{20}{24} \selectfont
 \lipsum

{\Huge Here is larger text}

\lipsum
\end{document}
```

LaTeX doesn't allow just any old font size in the documentclass call, so I've had to get around that with explicitly giving a fontsize at the begining. (This means that the page numbers are relatively very small now...)

Answer (score 4):

The most flexible solution to this problem that I know of is `pgfpages`.  It's an interface to TeX's shipout algorithms.  You can place as many pages of any size you want on each page.  It's documented in the PGF manual, albeit lightly.  Have a look at the source files that come with `beamer` to see how it's used and also this very popular post from Guido Diepen's blog: [“Creating latex-beamer handouts with notes”](http://www.guidodiepen.nl/2009/07/creating-latex-beamer-handouts-with-notes/)