# How to create a PDF with two A5 pages placed on A4-sized paper in ConTeXt?

Tags: context, paper-size, context-mkiv

I am trying to create a PDF where the text is placed on pages of A5, but two A5 sheets are placed on one A4 sheet which is in landscape mode, e.g.:

```
 _______________
|       |       |
|       |       |
|   A5  |   A5  |
|       |       |
|_______|_______|
```

I have tried this, but it just places A5 pages on the left side of the A4 sheet, no pages appear on the right side:

```
\setuppapersize[A5][A4, landscape]
\setuparranging[2*1, doublesided]
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided]
```

Comment: Would you please provide a MWE?

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/four-smaller-pages-in-one-page

Comment: related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-there-a-way-to-get-two-pages-in-one-with-latex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find information about imposition in the [new chapter about page design](http://context.aanhet.net/svn/contextman/context-reference/en/co-pagedesign.pdf). I used the option `2SIDE` as follows:

```
\setuppapersize [A5] [A4, landscape]
\setuparranging [2SIDE]
\starttext
\switchtobodyfont [380pt]

\dorecurse{6}{%
    \midaligned{\recurselevel}
    \page}

\stoptext
```