# How can I divide a page in 4 pieces?

Tags: tables, spacing, floats

I want to make a page like this?

[image]

This is done in word, and there's 4 separate text fields you can edit.
I don't have a MWE because I don't know where to start.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13055/four-smaller-pages-in-one-page

Comment: You might take a look at the `pdfpages`  documentation

Comment: Both solutions would make my page one forth of the size, is there a way to do it in one `.tex` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sets a 0.25in margin around each minipage, which comes to a 0.5in gap between minipages.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[margin=.25in, columnsep=.5in,noheadfoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}% MWE only
\pagestyle{empty}


% set vertical gap to .5in
\newlength{\columnheight}
\setlength{\columnheight}{\dimexpr 0.5\textheight-.25in}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% note that minipage resets these internally
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}% so these only apply between minipages

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[c][\columnheight][t]{\columnwidth}
Top left.

\lipsum[1]
\end{minipage}\par% or just add a blank line
\vfill% add vertical gap between minipages
\rotatebox{180}{\begin{minipage}[c][\columnheight][t]{\columnwidth}
Bottom left.

\lipsum[2]
\end{minipage}}\par% LaTeX likes to break pages/columns between paragraphs
\begin{minipage}[c][\columnheight][t]{\columnwidth}
Top right.

\lipsum[3]
\end{minipage}\par
\vfill
\rotatebox{180}{\begin{minipage}[c][\columnheight][t]{\columnwidth}
Bottom right.

\lipsum[4]
\end{minipage}}\par
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works like a charm!