# Include 5 pdf pages in one page with a blank page

Tags: pdfpages

Just encounter a small problem with Texmaker. I want to add 5 PDF pages in one PDF page with TexMaker. The layout I need is the one below :

[image]

I used the code here with Texmaker:

```
\includepdf[nup=2x3, pages={1-5},landscape=TRUE, columnstrict=true]{myfile.pdf}
```

But I don't know how can I get the layout that I want. I searched on forums and don't find the answer, but if you have a link that I didn't see it's also perfect !

I also have to repeat this operation since I have a pdf file with 45 pages and I want to have a final pdf file with the layout above and 5 pages per page.

Comment: Hi, welcome to TeX.SE! I don't think `pdfpages` can do that. I didn't see an option for such special layout in its manual. I would go with placing the pages separatly using TikZ.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome and the answer. I will have a look at TikZ then ! :)

Comment: I'm sure someone will post some full answer for this here soon. Just for clarification: Do you need this as part of a normal document, like in the appendix, or does your final PDF only consists of the included PDFs? Also, are you using A4 or Letter pagesize?

Comment: Thx for the answer Martin ! I only need for a final PDF only consists of the included PDFs. I'm using A4 landscape for now :)

Comment: With `pgfpages` you can create your own layout, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/151645/how-to-generate-pdf-with-6-slides-from-beamer-presentation/151652#151652

Comment: You would be more likely to get an answer sooner if you posted a minimal working example people could fix up for you, rather than making them start from scratch.

Comment: You don't really need Ti*k*Z for this. You could just use `graphicx` and `geometry` with a couple of `minipage`s --- or `coffin`, if you want to be cutting edge.