# Beamer presentation to a4 printable

Tags: beamer, printing, pgfpages

Hi I'm going to graduate in physics on tuesday and I'd love to have a printable nice formatted copy of my presentation. 
I tried adding

```
\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]
```

but compiling via pdflatex on OSx doesn't render anything more than the regular beamer presentation I made. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{chicago}
\usepackage{graphicx}
    \graphicspath{ {img/} }

\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[a4paper,border shrink=5mm,landscape]


%%% Personalizzazione del layout---articolata su cinque livelli.
\usetheme{Berkeley}         % layout complessivo. 
\useoutertheme{sidebar}     % layout esterno.

%%% Titolo e autore.
\title{*}
\subtitle{*}
\author{*}
\institute{*}
\date{*}
\logo{\includegraphics[width=15mm]{*}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
blabla
\end{document}
```

The last slide is a reference one

```
\begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{Bibliografia}
    \tiny
        \nocite{*}

    \bibliography{tesi}

\end{frame}
```

Comment: Just my thought: hasn't beamer an `handout` option, that suits your issue? `\usepackage[handout]{beamer}` Also: what errors dou you have in the log?

Comment: Can you describe how you expect the result to look like?

Comment: It is easiest to do this using a second document, I think, which just arranges the slides onto the page. At least, I find it easier.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'd like to have somehting like slides I made but that doesn't reseem too small on an a4 paper.

Comment: @DavideBarbieri Do I understand you correctly that your problem with the above code is that the slides do not fill the whole page? In that case I would suggest to print the "normal" beamer slides and select "fit to page" or similar from your printer dialogue. However a white boarder will remain, as a) your printer probably cannot print boarderless b) you're beamer slides have an aspect ratio of 4:3, which is different from the ratio of an A4 page.

Comment: @DavideBarbieri I am still unsure if I understood your question correctly. Can you maybe draw a quick sketch of how the beamer slide should be with respect to the paper page?

Comment: That's the problem I don't know what a nice template for rebinding a presentation to an a4 paper standard. http://www.legatoriasarcinelli.it/images/tesi-similpelle.jpg This is the tesi I'm going to have printed, although having the papers glued on a fraction I didn't know what a nice margin would have been

Comment: @DavideBarbieri A quick hint: if you put an `@` sign before a persons name, you can notify him/her about your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Warning:** totally opinion based.

- I would definitely go with something in portrait format. This is less cumbersome to turn pages.
- as beamer slides are designed to be read from some distance, the font size etc. is normally larger than in normal printing. To make reading more pleasant, I suggest multiple slides per page. The two in the example below might even be too large, maybe even 6 ones in two columns can fit a page.
- If you are going to have the pages in a glued binding, remember to have a bit more space on the inner margin. The example below adds `0.7cm`, but this highly depends on the exact binding technique, what paper is used and how many pages there are. Best would be to talk to your book binder for a good value.
- If you are going for double sided printing things gets more complicated, as the binding offset has to be placed alternating on the left and right side. Other documentclasses have `twosided` options, maybe it would be easier to set up a new document and include the slides there as images. Also I find that in twosided printing the margins should be asymmetric with a smaller inner margin (as the margins from both sides are besides each other) and bigger outer margins.
- last but not least: leave enough white space! If in doubt, make the margins even bigger.

(The layout is based on [Is there a way to get two pages in one with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-there-a-way-to-get-two-pages-in-one-with-latex#))

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfpages}

\makeatletter
\define@key{pgfpagesuselayoutoption}{horizontal shift}%
{\def\pgfpageoptionhshift{#1}}
\define@key{pgfpagesuselayoutoption}{vertical shift}%
{\def\pgfpageoptionvshift{#1}}
\makeatother

\pgfpagesdeclarelayout{2 on 1 shifted}
{
    \edef\pgfpageoptionheight{\the\paperwidth} % landscaped by default
    \edef\pgfpageoptionwidth{\the\paperheight}
    \def\pgfpageoptionborder{0pt}
    \def\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout{1}
    \def\pgfpageoptionhshift{0pt}
    \def\pgfpageoptionvshift{0pt}
}
{
    \pgfpagesphysicalpageoptions
    {%
        logical pages=2,%
        physical height=\pgfpageoptionheight,%
        physical width=\pgfpageoptionwidth,%
        current logical shipout=\pgfpageoptionfirstshipout%
    }
    \ifdim\paperheight>\paperwidth\relax
    % put side-by-side
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.25\pgfphysicalwidth+\pgfpageoptionhshift}{.5\pgfphysicalheight+\pgfpageoptionvshift}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=.5\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.75\pgfphysicalwidth+\pgfpageoptionhshift}{.5\pgfphysicalheight+\pgfpageoptionvshift}%
    }%
    \else
    % stack on top of one another
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{1}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth+\pgfpageoptionhshift}{.75\pgfphysicalheight+\pgfpageoptionvshift}%
    }%
    \pgfpageslogicalpageoptions{2}
    {%
        border shrink=\pgfpageoptionborder,%
        resized width=\pgfphysicalwidth,%
        resized height=.5\pgfphysicalheight,%
        center=\pgfpoint{.5\pgfphysicalwidth+\pgfpageoptionhshift}{.25\pgfphysicalheight+\pgfpageoptionvshift}%
    }%
    \fi    
}

\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1 shifted}[a4paper,border shrink=12mm, horizontal shift=0.7cm]

\usetheme{Berkeley}         
\useoutertheme{sidebar}    

\begin{document}

    \frame{frame1}
    \frame{frame2}

\end{document}
```

[image]