# How can I write a document in book format with horizontal page and 2 columns in LaTeX?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, two-column, columns, books, page

I am trying to create a document of book type, but instead of having pages in vertical orientation in which each page of the document is a page of the book, I want to orientate the page to be horizontal, and with two columns.

The reason of doing it is that I want to get a book in which each horizontal page of the LaTeX document refers to 2 pages of the book (each column representing a page).

It is possible? How can I get it?

Comment: This is called the `landscape` format. Just use `\documentclass[landscape,twocolumn]{book}`.

Comment: Why do you want this? It doesn't make sense to do this, imho.

Comment: "each horizontal page of the LaTeX document refers to 2 pages of the book"  -> does this mean you want to actually have two horizontal pages side by side with an end result of seemingly 4 pages? Research pdfpages or pdfjam and its pdfnup tool.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to get two pages in one with LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-there-a-way-to-get-two-pages-in-one-with-latex)

Comment: I want a single document page to have 2 columns of text, and each column to represent one page, with its own page numbering.