# How to create a specific page layout template?

Tags: layout

I'm searching for some ideas to create a template whose the page layout would be the same as this one ( http://www.jcbehareditions.com/images/36/extrait_7.pdf): two pages face to face. Any idea of how I could achieve that? This is a mwe written from your suggestions:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside,openany,twocolumn]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage [frenchb]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{landscape}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Notes about something}
\lipsum

\chapter{Notes about something else}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: In general `pgfpages` (not `pdfpages`) can put several logical pages on a single page without you worrying about page numbers/header etc. But since you make it clear that you need two logical pages on a single page in that particular form, I suggest `geometry` plus `twocolumn`. The later is the most vanilla approach and you do not have to worry about floating figures, `hyperref`, etc

Comment: That is an incomplete innards of a two sided document so is missing the preceding high quality art cover page the insert Is usually generated as single pages then the output is n-up rotated using print settings possibly stored in distiller options there are many ways to either set a virtual printer driver or other software to convert standard pages however if you insist on doing it with tex we need to consider what you want to convert do you have an mwe of say 4 lipsum pages to allow for the staggered covers and one inside pair of page 2-3  (just like say a birthday card)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Your request is for a very unconventional layout since It does not lend itself to booklet or normal publishing rules it is akin to that required for e-publishing. I emulated your sample which is frontispiece livre(2) and premier title(3) it is based on additional high res front and back cover (1) & (n).
To change the numbering from 2-3 the counters need to be amended per comments

This was very much an apprenticeship piece and as such has many failings. It could be much improved using macros for better page numbering, (note currently you may have to redefine style on some pages see comments :-)

It requires XeLaTeX to compile "right ways up" whilst working in a tex editor then needs a final run in LuaLaTeX  for rotation (see comments)

```
\documentclass[12pt, openany]{book} %,twocolumn, twoside conflicts with multicol pages
\usepackage [french]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % requires XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %requires pdfLaTeX so ignore
\usepackage{fontspec} % requires LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX
\setmainfont{Arial}

\usepackage[landscape, top=26mm,left=15mm,right=15mm]{geometry} % outer margins
\setlength{\columnsep}{30mm} % inner margin = double outer
\usepackage{rotating}% requires luatex
\usepackage{multicol} % better than two column as it easily 'wraps' second column
\usepackage{graphicx} % support images
\usepackage{pdflscape}% requires LuaLaTeX
\usepackage{calc} % supports numbering using the following
\newcounter{doubling} \newcounter{lessone} \newcounter{plusone} 

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagenumbering{arabic} % set default to 1
\fancypagestyle{plain}{% overrides page numbering only use one numbering type per document

% counters for 2-3, 4-5 etc for each sheet do not change sequence calculates left then right
     \setcounter{doubling} {2 * \value{page}} \setcounter{plusone} {1 + \value{doubling}}
     \fancyhead[E,O]{\bf\noindent \thedoubling \hfill \theplusone} % define 2-3 header

% counters for 1-2, 3-4 etc for each sheet do not change sequence calculates right then left comment the 2 lines above and uncomment next 2
   %\setcounter{doubling} {2 * \value{page}} \setcounter{lessone} {\value{doubling} - 1}
   %\fancyhead[E,O]{\bf\noindent \thelessone \hfill \thedoubling} % define 1-2 header

\fancyfoot{} \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} \renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}}  % clear all other fields

% IF pagenumbers do not appear in a section add this confirmation to each affected page
% \thispagestyle{plain}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mwe demonstration remove to use own text

\begin{document} % document will be rightways up for editing uncomment next line for final run
%\global\pdfpageattr{/Rotate 90} %requires LuaLaTeX
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{multicols}{2}
~\par % needed to start the page off
\noindent \includegraphics{./example.png}
\newline
\par \vspace{40mm}\Huge % title
La Sagesse du Potier
\par \vspace{5mm}\par % author
Jean Gire
\par \vspace{20mm}\normalsize % front matter
Du même auteur
\par
«Alain Girel ou le paradis retrouvé», textes de Jean Girel, Gérard Gay-Barbier et Danielle Le Goff, Photographies de Michel Horiot, 2002
\newline\par\it
J’ai choisi la céramique comme un instrument de découverte de la réalité.Et comme je suis fasciné par cette découverte,émerveillé par la vérité de la réalité,j’essaie de donner une forme communicable à cet émerveillement. La poterie,dans sa nudité,dans son vide,
dans son format à l’échelle de l’œil et de la main,m’apparaît comme le moyen le plus pur de parvenir à cette fin.
\normalfont
\chapter{Le monde dans un bol}
% rough demo text thus may raise an Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)
\it{
«Un jour, un homme prit de la glaise, et modela une forme de récipient. Par mégarde, il la laissa tomber dans le foyer. Il la retrouva cuite le lendemain dans les cendres. La poterie était née.»
}\normalfont \newline

L’invention de la poterie est souvent décrite ainsi,comme une sorte de cueillette. Le conte est séduisant,et l’expérience mérite d’être tentée de nouveau.Il s’agit d’abord de trouver de l’argile.J’ai visité des centaines de carrières,de trous à terre,j’ai creusé dans tous les lieux dont le toponyme évoque,dans un parler ou dans un autre,l’argile ou son usage : « Les Argilières », « les Poteries », les
« Oullières »,les « Tupiniers »… Je n’ai jamais trouvé une argile brute prête à cuire.Il y a tou- jours des cailloux à enlever,des grains qui éclatent à la cuisson ou des bouts de bois,donc des éléments en trop.Il y manque toujours aussi quelque chose,ce qui fait que la terre colle aux doigts,ou ne se supporte pas,fend au séchage, ou éclate à la cuisson. Il faut lui ajouter des sables,ou de l’argile déjà cuite pilée.

Quand la pâte est prête,on peut essayer de soire,le mortier,la boîte,le cuvier… Tous ces vocables – on pourrait en citer des dizaines
d’autres avec leurs variantes locales – désignent des récipients,des formes conçues pour recevoir.Le propre de la poterie est d’abord
d’accueillir. Sa seconde fonction découle de la première :servir,verser ce qu’elle a accueilli.Le corps de la pièce se transforme dans ce but,se prolonge en col,bec,lèvre,goulot.La manipulation,le stockage,l’obturation,l’assise au sol ou sur le feu, exigent d’autres accessoires : anse, oreille, queue, bouchon, couvercle, mamelon, téton… et déterminent d’autres transformations :le pot repose sur un pied,un cul,un talon.La fonction crée l’organe :il y a dans la poterie quelque chose de profondément organique,elle se constitue comme une créature, plus que comme une création. Le vocabulaire typologique est celui du corps.

On retrouvera dans les parties du four les mêmes analogies avec le têtier,le gueulard,la bouche,le sifflet,la flamme qui lèche le flanc
des pots… Le déclin des ateliers de poterie d’usage, amorcé avec l’industrialisation de la faïence fine et de la porcelaine au XIX e siècle s’est précipité ensuite avec l’apparition du fer-blanc, de l’aluminium,de l’inox,du pyrex,des plastiques et des verres. Parallèlement à cette disparition,émerge une conception de la poterie comme un art égal à la peinture ou la sculpture.Comme dans toute renaissance,le créateur doit poser de nouveaux fondements à son entreprise et va trouver l’impulsion dans les civilisations lointaines ou passées pour qui la poterie est un art majeur,voire sacré.Le japonisme,l’engouement pour les porcelaines chi
noises antérieures aux Ming, ou encore la découverte de la céramique précolombienne avec l’ouverture du musée ethnographique du Trocadéro.

\lipsum[1-5]\par
\thispagestyle{plain}

\chapter{Notes about \newline something else}

\lipsum[3-6]
%    \thispagestyle{plain}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I give you the promised bounty! Could you, please, tell me how I could give the first page its proper number? In my attempt, it gives me the number two.

Comment: I have removed much duplication and simplified change between number styles

Answer (score 0):

I think is just the perception set a 2 columns page landscaped rotated 90 degrees CW and latex will do the magic
[Check here](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Page_size_and_margins#Paper_size.2C_orientation_and_margins)

```
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letter, landscape, margin=2in}
\usepackage{multicol}
 \begin{multicols}{2}
\global\pdfpageattr\expandafter{\the\pdfpageattr/Rotate 90}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  I'm afraid this doesn't achieve what the layout is: two proper pages (with numbers, headers etc. on each landscape page).

Comment: @Rafael Zemog: Thanks for your help, but in so far as it does not work, I'm going to edit your suggestion with a mwe which integrates your proposal.

Comment: check [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/783/is-there-a-way-to-get-two-pages-in-one-with-latex)